# Why are my "Core Web Vitals" almost always empty?

Tags: google-pagespeed, google-search-console

In many of my websites the "Core Web Vitals" are still at 0. It's been a long time now, and we have had several visits, but still often both desktop and mobile are at zero.

[image]

and when they are not zero, they are often negative
[image]

even if testing the pages with pagespeed everything is perfect.
[image]

So the question is: this thing work?

Out of hundreds of thousands of visits there will have been a couple made with a mobile phone and a couple with a PC ...

- is it possible that some sites are still at 0?
- How many visits does it take to start filling in this data?
- Do they all have to be on chrome?

This thing is more and more annoying, I always think that I have something on my sites or on my server that does not allow this thing to work properly, but I never find anything that can bother him, he just seems to not want to look .. .

Some sites have been looked at (always on the same server and often the same structure/CMS), some numbers have grown, and when it happens there are movements/increases in site visits... So it becomes more and more unpleasant that some sites are watched and others not.

- Can you help me understand why this happens?
- Is there any way to make it easier to scan this thing?
- Do I spend the whole day visiting my sites with chrome?

Comment: Are the first two images are from Google Search Console tool? if so, add its tag, maybe you'll get more attention for this question. BTW, it's "Core Web Vitals" (not "essential web signals").

Comment: Thanks, modified.